# Change navigation drawer selected item with replace fragment

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have Navigation Drawer with default code. But, when I want to replace my fragments. Navigation Drawer menu selected item background color is not changing.

I have 2 fragments. First saving data to sqlite db and replacing to second fragment. Now I want to change background of second fragment with java code.

[navigation drawer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1G9vR.png)

I want to change item background color, when I'm in a fragment.(if fragment A, background color is on. if fragment B, background color is on)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can show the selected item by putting `android:checkable="true"` on the menu item.